# SQL Server 2014 - MainTable & TempTable - IF Not Exists Insert Else Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have two tables with same columns on Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

MainTable and TempTable.

I would like to enter the updated / fresh data from TempTable onto MainTable avoiding duplicates.

The **MainTable** looks like the following:

[image]

The **TempTable** looks like the following:

[image]

The data in the **TempTable** will constantly change. It may have updated data or new rows.

What I am trying to achieve is, insert / update the data from TempTable onto MainTable.

**TempTable**: - In this example, The row with *Numbr 101 and 104* has the updated data. It also has new rows with *Numbr 105 and 106*. I would like to update the data of 101 and 104 and also insert 105 and 106.

Please advice as I am new to SQL.

---

**UPDATE1:**

After using the following query:

```
--Insert New
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE
SELECT A.*
FROM 
TempTable as A 
LEFT JOIN MainTable as B
ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE B.Number IS NULL

--Update Old
UPDATE A
SET A.Number = B.Number,
    A.Name = B.Name,
    A.LastActive = B.LastActive,
    A.Country = B.Country
FROM 
TempTable as A 
LEFT JOIN MainTable as B
ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE B.Number IS NOT NULL
```

The Output of **MainTable**:

[image]

It worked, but when the data in **TempTable** is updated and new data is added:

[image]

The Result after running the query:

MainTable and TempTable respectively

[image]

The new Row 108 got added (From **TempTable --> MainTable**) but the updated Row 106 had no effect and the value in TempTable got copied from MainTable.

Comment: Check out the MERGE statement (read this entire page, but you can skim down to the "Using MERGE to Insert and Update" for a faster answer): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What about 102 and 103?

Comment: @BaconBits They may or may not change. This is just an example and I have hundreds of rows.

Comment: @pmbAustin The merge didn't quite really work.

Comment: @Tango Right, but what should happen to MainTable when 102 and 103 are there and TempTable doesn't have 102 and 103?  Are the records deleted from MainTable?  Are they left as is in MainTable?

Comment: @BaconBits The records are never deleted from MainTable. They are left as they are. The updated data or a new data is on TempTable.

Comment: Merge statement is perfect for this.  The syntax is a bit wonky, but it works a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Insert New
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE
SELECT A.*
FROM 
TempTable as A 
LEFT JOIN MainTable as B
ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE B.Number IS NULL

--Update Old
UPDATE A
SET A.Number = B.Number,
    A.Name = B.Name,
    A.LastActive = B.LastActive,
    A.Country = B.Country
FROM 
TempTable as A 
LEFT JOIN MainTable as B
ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE B.Number IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Don't update the number if that's your join predicate... and in the case of update, you can just do an INNER JOIN and leave off the WEHRE clause

Comment: @pmbAustin and LONG, Please check the update in the original post.

Comment: Yeah, this answer has the update statement messed up a lot. Switch the A and B aliases (TempTable B LEFT JOIN MainTable A) in the join and it should work a bit better...

Comment: @pmbAustin thanks switching a & b aliases work! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE
SELECT A.*
FROM 
TempTable as A 
LEFT JOIN MainTable as B
ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE B.Number IS NULL

--Update Old
UPDATE A
SET A.Name = B.Name,
A.LastActive = B.LastActive,
A.Country = B.Country
FROM TempTable as B 
INNER JOIN MainTable as A
 ON B.Number = A.Number
WHERE A.Name <> B.Name,
 A.LastActive <> B.LastActive,
 A.Country <> B.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `Numbr` is a key or unique field in both tables.  If that's not the case, then you should not use these queries.  Additionally, the field should be indexed in both tables if performance is a problem.

This is the simplest way:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO MainTable (Numbr, Name, LastActive, Country)
SELECT t.Numbr, t.Name, t.LastActive, t.Country
FROM TempTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MainTable m WHERE m.Numbr = t.Numbr);

UPDATE m
    SET Name = t.Name,
        LastActive = t.LastActive,
        Country = t.Country
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TempTable t
    ON m.Numbr = t.Numbr
WHERE m.Name <> t.Name
    OR m.LastActive <> t.LastActive
    OR m.Country <> t.Country;
COMMIT;
```

Note that if Name, LastActive, or Country are nullable fields then the syntax gets much more verbose.  For example, if all three fields are nullable, then you should use this syntax:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO MainTable (Numbr, Name, LastActive, Country)
SELECT t.Numbr, t.Name, t.LastActive, t.Country
FROM TempTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MainTable m WHERE m.Numbr = t.Numbr);

UPDATE m
    SET Name = t.Name,
        LastActive = t.LastActive,
        Country = t.Country
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TempTable t
    ON m.Numbr = t.Numbr
WHERE m.Name <> t.Name
    OR (m.Name IS NULL AND t.Name IS NOT NULL)
    OR (m.Name IS NOT NULL AND t.Name IS NULL)
    OR m.LastActive <> t.LastActive
    OR (m.LastActive IS NULL AND t.LastActive IS NOT NULL)
    OR (m.LastActive IS NOT NULL AND t.LastActive IS NULL)
    OR m.Country <> t.Country
    OR (m.Country IS NULL AND t.Country IS NOT NULL)
    OR (m.Country IS NOT NULL AND t.Country IS NULL);
COMMIT;
```

If you absolutely need to minimize the number of writes, then you should break up the `UPDATE` statement into one query for each field.  This may run faster or may run slower, so just because you're writing less doesn't mean the queries will execute faster.  Again, I've assumed there are no nullable fields in your system:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO MainTable (Numbr, Name, LastActive, Country)
SELECT t.Numbr, t.Name, t.LastActive, t.Country
FROM TempTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MainTable m WHERE m.Numbr = t.Numbr);

UPDATE m
    SET Name = t.Name
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TempTable t
    ON m.Numbr = t.Numbr
WHERE m.Name <> t.Name;

UPDATE m
    SET LastActive = t.LastActive
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TempTable t
    ON m.Numbr = t.Numbr
WHERE m.LastActive <> t.LastActive;

UPDATE m
    SET Country = t.Country
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TempTable t
    ON m.Numbr = t.Numbr
WHERE m.Country <> t.Country;
COMMIT;
```